# Chrome remote debugging protocol, getAllStyleSheets() method not found

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to access all stylesheets from a Chrome extension using the Remote debugging protocol. According to https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/CSS/ there should be a method for this:

> A client can also discover all the existing stylesheets with the
>   getAllStyleSheets() method

However I was unable to execute this. Is this implemented? Is there another way of accessing the CSSOM from a background script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *was* implemented, but [has been since removed.](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/devtools/protocol.json?revision=166228)

> DevTools: [CSS] remove `getAllStylesheets` method from protocol
>
> This patch removes `getAllStylesheets` method from protocol. Instead,
>   clients should track `styleSheetAdded`/`styleSheetRemoved` events to
>   maintain actual stylesheet set.

Comment: Do you know if styleSheetAdded event will allow access to CSSOM? Thank you